# iOS - How to pass touchEvent done on UITableView to its parent UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am implementing my own SplitViewController. I am facing issue of handling touch event. I have one UIViewController in which I have added one UIView on left side and right side I have added one UITableView. Now issue is when I swipe on tableView I need to trap touchMoved event on parent controller to animate right side view (tableView) over left view. But I guess tableView is handling touchMoved and not passing it to its Parent UIViewController. Let me whether there is any way to over come this issue or not? What I need is tableView should be scrollable but when there is enough horizontal swipe i need to animate tableView with every touchMoved call.

Let me know if any further detail is required.

Comment: Can you explain better your final goal? I'm not sure what you mean with `when there is enough horizontal swipe i need to animate tableView with every touchMoved call`

Comment: Have you tried in touchMoved `CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superView];`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want something that works like most apps do these days correct? Swiping horizontally reveals a menu of some sort?